# shellScript to execute a command in new shell from SSHing

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I am using below two commands to connect to a remote VM host and access the docker bash.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/rsa opc@100.111.99.164
sudo docker exec -it MT bash
```

First I run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/rsa opc@100.111.99.164` which in response connects to the specified Machine and then I run `sudo docker exec -it MT bash` inside the terminal of this new machine.
All these I do manually and there are various such instances that I use to connect to, in a day. I want to write a script that automate this process. But the problem is, when I write the aforementioned commands in a .sh file and run it, the second command i.e `sudo docker exec -it MT bash` is not executed and that is expected too because the script is not running in the terminal of the machine (100.111.99.164) which I'm connected to.

I would really appreciate if someone could suggest a solution.

Comment: Have you tried putting sudo right after ssh... on the same line?

Comment: See ["How to ssh from within a bash script?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895185/how-to-ssh-from-within-a-bash-script)

Comment: Automation tools like Ansible, Chef, or Salt Stack are designed for this case.  Not for getting debugging shells on arbitrary containers, but there's probably some higher-level administrative task you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `docker exec` command to ssh command.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/rsa -tt opc@100.111.99.164 "sudo su - root -c 'docker exec -it MT bash'"
```

or if you want to run command in container then you can pass the command to container

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/rsa -tt opc@100.111.99.164 "sudo su - root -c 'docker exec -it MT bash  -c \"echo hello from cotainer\"'"
```

Comment: what command did you try to execute inside the container? and btw the answer was supposed to above issue ;)

Comment: I tried to use ```cd``` command. 
```cd /logs/ETL/app```